# Weird WebView behavior when playing Flash game

Tags: android, flash, webview, android-webview

I'm developing an Android app that embeds a Flash game in a WebView container. In particular, it's a Solitaire game that requires the user to drag cards around. In a WebView with specified width and height, the card would get "stuck" as the user tries to drag it, rendering the game unplayable. However, I discovered that in full screen, finger dragging input works just fine. Does anyone have any insight regarding Flash Player behavior in WebView?

Answer (score 1):

Use this in your webView

```
webView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            v.onTouchEvent(event);
            return false;
        }
    });
```